# How to use wcf service in Client Application?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

Server side code is,

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UploadDamagedImage", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]        
        NewClsMessage UploadDamagedImage(Details ObjDt123);
```

Client side code is,

```
Details ObjDt = new Details();
            ObjDt.Name = "hi";
            ObjDt.Email = "hi@gmail.com";
            ObjDt.ContactNumber = "3698754215";
            ObjDt.DeviceModel = "E23";
            ObjDt.Problem = "Repair";
            ObjDt.Besttimetocontact = "9am";
```

Here,I am getting the error is 'Object reference is not set to an instance of the object'.
Is there any neccessary to use the same object name for both client and server side?
How to solve this problem?

**Edit**

Client code is,

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:53865/Service1.svc/UploadDamagedImage");
            Details ObjDt = new Details();
            ObjDt.Name = "hi";
            ObjDt.Email = "hi@gmail.com";
            ObjDt.ContactNumber = "3698754215";
            ObjDt.DeviceModel = "E23";
            ObjDt.Problem = "Repair";
            ObjDt.Besttimetocontact = "9am";

byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\Projects\6mb\1.jpg");
            ObjDt.ImgUpload = bytes;
 DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Details));

            MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
            ser.WriteObject(mem, ObjDt);
            string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray(), 0, (int)mem.Length);
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_UploadStringCompleted);
            webClient.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
            webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            webClient.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", data);
```

Server side code is,

```
public NewClsMessage UploadDamagedImage(Details ObjDt123)
        {
  NewClsMessage ObjNewClsMessage = new NewClsMessage();
            try
            {
 Random rand = new Random();
                int strRandNo = rand.Next();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ObjDt.ImgUpload);  
    Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
  catch (Exception ex)
            {

            } 
}
```

Comment: On which line does the exception occur? And what code do you have to call the service (in the client)?

Comment: And on what line does the exception occur?

Comment: In server side got the exception

Comment: You're still not specifying on which line the exception is occuring. Where is variable ObjDt defined in your server-side code? This doesn't seem to be the complete code since your method UploadDamagedImage defines a return type but the code doesn't return anything. Please post the complete compiling code.

Comment: when entering into the server side code i got error..code is public NewClsMessage UploadDamagedImage(Details ObjDt123)

Comment: Please turn on breaking when an exception is thrown: menu Debug -> Exceptions (or control-alt-e), and check Common Language Runtime Exceptions, first column (Thrown). Also make sure you are attached to the running service. Now, when running your solution, Visual Studio should break on the line where the exception is thrown. So... which line throws the exception?